# Tab appiication Landscape mode on tianium

Tags: ios, titanium

I am making application with tabGroup.

However when I rotate the device screen doesn't change ,even I set like this in tiapp.xml

Is it impossible to rotate tab application??

```
<iphone>
    <orientations device="iphone">
        <orientation>Ti.UI.PORTRAIT</orientation>
        <orientation>Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_LEFT</orientation>
        <orientation>Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_RIGHT</orientation>
    </orientations>
    <orientations device="ipad">
        <orientation>Ti.UI.PORTRAIT</orientation>
        <orientation>Ti.UI.UPSIDE_PORTRAIT</orientation>
        <orientation>Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_LEFT</orientation>
        <orientation>Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_RIGHT</orientation>
    </orientations>
</iphone>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try giving `orientationModes` in window property like.

```
var win1 = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor : 'red',
    orientationModes : [Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_LEFT, Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_RIGHT, Ti.UI.PORTRAIT]
});
```

It worked for me.

[image]

Comment: I'ts great suggestion,however it doesn't work form . it might depends on the version or something. my titanium SDK is 4.0.0.GA

Answer (score 0):

Set the orientation in your tiapp.xml in the `<plist><dict>`section

```
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~iphone</key>
            <array>
                <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
            </array>
            <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
            <array>
                <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
                <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
                <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
                <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
            </array>
```